# Debugging delivered applications

Tags: javascript, .net, debugging, remote-debugging, error-logging

Say you have a .net application you delivered to your client, with a button, this button executes some code, the user clicks this button and it crashes with a generic error message.

Any ideas or tips on how to be able to debug such an error while not having the enviroment of that error under your control? how and what should i log while executing my code to be able to pinpoint the problem just by asking the client to email me an error log?

I would be grateful if you could suggest similars techniques for javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question but probably the first thing is to log the exception details. There are plenty of libraries that'll help you do it without you having to write all the low level code (NLog, log4net etc., just pick one). Catch any unhandled exceptions in your application (exact method depends on the application type) and pass them to the logging framework.

From the stack trace of an exception you can probably gather useful information but it may not be enough. Use the logging framework to log more information than just the exceptions, perhaps at critical points in your application. Make it optional so that you can turn it on but have it turned off usually for better performance.

Other than that, use your imagination and the tools at your disposal, and ask any other more specific questions.

Comment: so there is no typical aspects of application behavoir or parts of code that should be logged to help dubugging? you just log the exception and its details along with any parts of the code i see as critical depending on the context of my code?

Comment: That's my take on it, yes. Now I just saw the javascript tag there and things may be different depending on what the application actually is - for ASP.Net apps you might also log the state of the request for instance, with as many server variables as possible. But in the general case, there's not really anything generic you can use as far as I know.